# Type class composition in Scala for Tuples?

Tags: scala, typeclass

I was trying to implement a slightly more Scala friendly version of `java.util.Scanner` e.g. instead of doing `scanner.nextInt()`, I wanted it to parse any type class for which a parser is defined e.g. `scanner.read[Int]` instead. Here is the gist of my attempt:

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, Reader, InputStreamReader, StringReader, InputStream}
import java.util.StringTokenizer

class InputReader(reader: BufferedReader) extends Iterator[String] with AutoCloseable {
  def this(reader: Reader) = this(new BufferedReader(reader))
  def this(inputStream: InputStream) = this(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
  def this(str: String) = this(new StringReader(str))

  private[this] val tokenizers = Iterator.continually(reader.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null).map(new StringTokenizer(_)).buffered

  @inline private[this] def tokenizer(): Option[StringTokenizer] = {
    while(tokenizers.nonEmpty && !tokenizers.head.hasMoreTokens) tokenizers.next()
    if (tokenizers.nonEmpty) Some(tokenizers.head) else None
  }

  def read[A: Parser]: A = implicitly[Parser[A]].apply(next())

  def tillEndOfLine(): String = tokenizer().get.nextToken("\n\r")
  override def next() = tokenizer().get.nextToken()
  override def hasNext = tokenizer().nonEmpty
  override def close() = reader.close()
}

trait Parser[A] {
  def apply(s: String): A
}
object Parser {
  def apply[A](f: String => A) = new Parser[A] {
    override def apply(s: String) = f(s)
  }
  implicit val stringParser: Parser[String] = Parser(identity)
  implicit val charParser: Parser[Char] = Parser(s => s.ensuring(_.length == 1, s"Expected Char; found $s").head)
  implicit val booleanParser: Parser[Boolean] = Parser(_.toBoolean)
  implicit val intParser: Parser[Int] = Parser(_.toInt)
  implicit val longParser: Parser[Long] = Parser(_.toLong)
  implicit val bigIntParser: Parser[BigInt] = Parser(BigInt(_))
  implicit val doubleParser: Parser[Double] = Parser(_.toDouble)
  implicit val bigDecimalParser: Parser[BigDecimal] = Parser(BigDecimal(_))
}
```

This makes it possible to define custom parsers and used as:

```
val reader = new InputReader(System.in)
reader.read[Int]
reader.read[String]
```

But, now, given that I know how to read an `Int` and `String`, how can I do this `reader.read[(Int, String)]` ?

Here is my attempt.

First, I change the `Parser` type class to take in a `InputReader` itself:

```
trait Parser[A] {
  def apply(context: InputReader): A
}
object Parser {
  def apply[A](f: String => A) = new Parser[A] {
    override def apply(context: InputReader) = f(context.next())
  }
}
```

And, then I define a `Parser` for a `Tuple2`:

```
implicit def tupleParser[A: Parser, B: Parser]: Parser[(A, B)] = new Parser[(A, B)] {
  override def apply(context: InputReader) = implicitly[Parser[A]].apply(context) -> implicitly[Parser[B]].apply(context)
}
```

This let's me call `reader.read[(Int, String)]`. But this is incredibly verbose as I now have to define parsers for all n-Tuples. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why not using Scala [parser combinators](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.2/scala-parser-combinators/#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers)?

Comment: @cchantep: This is for consuming unstructured input e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @cchantep: Also I was just proving this an illustrative example. In general, I am interested in stratgeies for generating type-classes for tuples whose elements have type classes...

Comment: You could have a look at Shapeless: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless